# QGIS 3 - Editing Issues

Tags: editing, nodes

My nodes in editing keep disappearing when I hover over them and wont let me edit anything. If you over over the center of the polygon, you can see the nodes, but not edit any of them. You can move the entire feature, but I cannot seem to move any nodes. This arose yesterday, and no restarts or new projects will solve the issue.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

D'oh! - You have to have a search radius higher than 0.00 for the nodes to be editable. I changed mine to 1.00 and am back in business. This is done in Settings - Digitizing

Source : QGIS Help